# Calculation of specific dimension

Tags: calculator

I have not found correct formula for calculating length out of other dimensions.

I have a plate.

I have given Height = 0.585 mm, Weigth 25000 kg, Width = 2 m Density is 7.874 g/cm3

And I need Length.

Please can you specify how to calculate exactly that I can understand how to do it?

I need it for some calculating tools

I know its a bit stupid to ask this...

BR,
Patric

Comment: 1. this is maths. 2. `g/cm3` is not volume but density so the formula is `density = mass/volume`. 3. you did not mention the shape and height of the object.

Comment: I've written a c# program using it. Do have a look if you need it. https://dotnetfiddle.net/lTwRIT

Comment: Thank you! I really needed this one :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

25000000g/7,874g/cm3 = 3175006,35cm3
3175006,35 cm3  = H * W * L
3175006,35 cm3/(0,0585cm*200cm) = L 
L = 271368,06cm